# How group by with Grouper but i want use the most recent date as reference in freq

Tags: python, pandas

I want use the last date as reference, not the firts date as the code do, in pandas Grouper.

the idea is the next.

My df is

```
date       value    c1   c2

2019-03-06  500000.0  1   1

2019-03-16  500000.0  2   2

2019-04-06  300000.0  1    1
```

when I use:

```py
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date',freq='30D')):
```

```
2019-03-06  1000000.0  3

2019-04-05  300000.0  1
```

but i want

```
2019-03-06  500000.0  1

2019-04-05  800000.0  3
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to your problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think that should be 31 days

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date',freq='31D',closed='right', label='right')).sum()
Out[325]: 
               value  c1  c2
date                        
2019-03-06  500000.0   1   1
2019-04-06  800000.0   3   3
```